# sf::Image::saveToFile() fails with "Failed to save image"?

Tags: c++, animation, sfml

I'm trying to, only using SMFL and no other external libraries, capture 120 frames per second and saving them into a folder called "captured_frames" which I have to manually add in the executable folder before running the code. The problem is whenever I run the below code I repeatedly get the error "Failed to save image ''"
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hqXc.png)

I tried to save it as induvial png's directly into the folder of the executable but that doesn't worth either. I also tried lowering the number of frames to be captured in a second, which also failed. I changed the folder from read-only to read-write, and the folder is in the same folder as the .vcxproj (Im using VS). This is the code, in bold is of interest:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Frame Capture");
    sf::Clock clock;
    const float captureInterval = 1.0f / 120.0f;
    int frameCount = 0;
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle1(sf::Vector2f(200, 100));
    rectangle1.setPosition(0, 200);
    rectangle1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);

    sf::RectangleShape rectangle2(sf::Vector2f(200, 100));
    rectangle2.setPosition(300, 200);
    rectangle2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    sf::RectangleShape rectangle3(sf::Vector2f(200, 100));
    rectangle3.setPosition(700, 200);
    rectangle3.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
//capturing frames

        

> if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= captureInterval) {
>             sf::Texture texture;
>             texture.create(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);
>             texture.update(window);
> 
>             sf::Image frameImage = texture.copyToImage();
>             std::string filename = "captured_frames/frame_" + std::to_string(frameCount) + ".png";
>             frameImage.saveToFile(filename);
> 
>             std::cout << "Frame captured and saved: " << filename << std::endl;
> 
>             clock.restart();
>             ++frameCount;
>         }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // Draw graphics
        window.draw(rectangle1);
        window.draw(rectangle2);
        window.draw(rectangle3);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I am getting this error, which I assume means the code doesn't have permission to memory: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFC6367646 (sfml-graphics-2.dll) in SFML.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001F4F761E7

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does `frameImage.getSize()` returns? Image should not be empty. And does the app have permission to write in that folder?

Comment: @Ripi2 The frame isn't empty, it returns the correct x and y value. By permission do you mean through file explorer? Or is there something in VS I have to do. In file explorer all access is granted.

Comment: @Ripi2 I opened VS as admin, still doesn't work

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @JesperJuhl The page was a good read but couldnt you post that link to any question?

Comment: @JKombos "couldnt you post that link to any question?" - Probably, at least for most, but that doesn't mean it's not good. Rather it means that people should start learning the tools they have available and then they wouldn't have to ask so many *really basic* questions.